# Search engines in pre-Google age

Tags: search-engine

It is well-known that, in the turn of the century, Google stood out of other search engines because of its revolutionary PageRank algorithm (despite the fact that mathematically, PageRank is just a very simple application of Perron-Frobenius theorem). However, very little information about those search algorithms used by pre-Google search engines can be found on the web.

Does anybody know how big names like **Lycos, Alta Vista, Excite, Yahoo** or **Ask Jeeves** perform web search and page ranking? Is there any material that documents those algorithms in more details?

For instance, I learn from this [short history of early search engines](http://www.thehistoryofseo.com/The-Industry/Short_History_of_Early_Search_Engines.aspx) that Excite did *"use statistical analysis of word relationships to improve relevancy of searches on the Internet"*, while Yahoo maintained *"a highly regarded directory of sites that were cataloged by human editors"*. That's a valuable piece of information, but the descriptions are still too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this documentary about the history of the internet (up to 2008) called Download: The History of the Internet. I think it mentioned that yahoo curated and categorized popular websites by hand.

I think it worked like an address book, the websites needed to opt-in and provide yahoo with it's web address and category.